# ASP.NET Core 3.1 MVC JWT Login return 401

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, jwt, asp.net-core-mvc

I have a problem , jwt authentication return 401 Error.
Token was created but always return 401 error.

I used layered architecture. I tried many things on startup.cs. JWT and startup.cs code in below. Will be updated if you want to look at another code.

JwtHelper Code:

```
 public class JwtHelper : ITokenHelper
    {
        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }
        private TokenOptions _tokenOptions;
        private DateTime _accessTokenExpiration;
        public JwtHelper(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
            _tokenOptions = Configuration.GetSection("TokenOptions").Get<TokenOptions>();

        }
        public AccessToken CreateToken(User user, List<OperationClaim> operationClaims)
        {
            _accessTokenExpiration = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(_tokenOptions.AccessTokenExpiration);
            var securityKey = SecurityKeyHelper.CreateSecurityKey(_tokenOptions.SecurityKey);
            var signingCredentials = SigningCredentialsHelper.CreateSigningCredentials(securityKey);
            var jwt = CreateJwtSecurityToken(_tokenOptions, user, signingCredentials, operationClaims);
            var jwtSecurityTokenHandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
            var token = jwtSecurityTokenHandler.WriteToken(jwt);

            return new AccessToken
            {
                Token = token,
                Expiration = _accessTokenExpiration
            };

        }

        public JwtSecurityToken CreateJwtSecurityToken(TokenOptions tokenOptions, User user,
            SigningCredentials signingCredentials, List<OperationClaim> operationClaims)
        {
            var jwt = new JwtSecurityToken(
                issuer: tokenOptions.Issuer,
                audience: tokenOptions.Audience,
                expires: _accessTokenExpiration,
                notBefore: DateTime.Now,
                claims: SetClaims(user, operationClaims),
                signingCredentials: signingCredentials
            );
            return jwt;
        }

        private IEnumerable<Claim> SetClaims(User user, List<OperationClaim> operationClaims)
        {
            var claims = new List<Claim>();
            claims.AddNameIdentifier(user.id.ToString());
            claims.AddEmail(user.Email);
            claims.AddName($"{user.FirstName} {user.LastName}");
            claims.AddRoles(operationClaims.Select(c => c.name).ToArray());

            return claims;
        }
    }
```

Statup.cs

```
  public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddCors();
            services.AddAntiforgery(o => o.HeaderName = "XSRF-TOKEN");
            services.AddControllersWithViews();
            services.AddRazorPages();
            var tokenOptions = Configuration.GetSection("TokenOptions").Get<TokenOptions>();

            services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
                .AddJwtBearer(options =>
                {
                    options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                    {
                        ValidateIssuer = true,
                        ValidateAudience = true,
                        ValidateLifetime = true,
                        ValidIssuer = tokenOptions.Issuer,
                        ValidAudience = tokenOptions.Audience,
                        ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                        IssuerSigningKey = SecurityKeyHelper.CreateSecurityKey(tokenOptions.SecurityKey)
                    };
                });


            services.AddControllersWithViews();
            services.AddDependencyResolvers(new ICoreModule[] {
                new CoreModule()
            });
            services.AddAuthentication(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddCookie(o => {
        o.LoginPath = "/Auth/Login";
    });
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
                // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
                app.UseHsts();
            }
            app.UseCors(builder => builder.WithOrigins("https://localhost:44378").AllowAnyHeader());
            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseStaticFiles();

            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseAuthorization();

            app.UseAuthentication();
            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    pattern: "{controller=Customer}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
            });
            app.UseStatusCodePages();
        }
```

I have been searching for 1 week but I did not found.

Comment: Look at your compiler warnings. `app.UseAuthentication` needs to go **before** `app.UseAuthorization`. That's just one issue, there might be more.

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto unfortunately it didn't work. :(

Answer (score 0):

After when you register JwtToken handler, this one

```
services.AddAuthentication(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddCookie(o => {
        o.LoginPath = "/Auth/Login";
```

Make your default Authentication Scheme be came `CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme`, which use cookie as validation.

The code should be

```
services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, opts => 
{
    opts.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
})
    .AddJwtBearer(options =>
    {
        options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
        {
            ValidateIssuer = true,
            ValidateAudience = true,
            ValidateLifetime = true,
            ValidIssuer = tokenOptions.Issuer,
            ValidAudience = tokenOptions.Audience,
            ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
            IssuerSigningKey = SecurityKeyHelper.CreateSecurityKey(tokenOptions.SecurityKey)
        };
    })
    .AddCookie(o => {
        o.LoginPath = "/Auth/Login";
    });;
```

And as @Camilo Terevinto mention, `app.UseAuthentication` must come before `app.UseAuthorization`.

Comment: View re-direction are complete difference concept than authentication feel free apply your own logic